# Zone to use to convert UK utm data to longitude, and latitude

Tags: python, utm

I'm currently working on a UK vehicle accident dataframe and I'd like to convert easting and northing utm data to longitude and latitude, and then into regions. I am unsure about which zone to use in the function despite searching the internet.

My current function works but I'm unsure about the zones and further creating a column converting longitude and latitude into regions.

Curent Function:

```
def rule(row):
    lat, lon = utm.to_latlon(row["location_easting_osgr"], row["location_northing_osgr"], 30, 'U')
    return pd.Series({"lat": lat, "long": lon})
df = df.merge(df_subset.apply(rule, axis=1), left_index= True, right_index= True)
```

Comment: Are you sure those eastings and northings are UTM, and not the Ordnance Survey National Grid? Using the OSNG would make a lot more sense for the UK, as the UK straddles, if I'm not mistaken, three UTM zones, with a zone boundary running right through Greater London!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikipedia has all the zone information in this image:
[image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system#/media/File:Universal_Transverse_Mercator_zones.svg)

Most of the UK is in zone 30U. So it looks like you have it right.

Alternatively you could just use the longitudinal zone and the hemisphere:

```
lat, lon = utm.to_latlon(row["location_easting_osgr"], row["location_northing_osgr"], 30, northern=FALSE)
```

Comment: You can inline the image and keep it clickable, if you want: `[![](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b7/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_zones.svg/1920px-Universal_Transverse_Mercator_zones.svg.png)](
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system#/media/File:Universal_Transverse_Mercator_zones.svg)` (explanation: `![description](link)` is an image, `[description](link)` is a clickable link, and then `[![](imagelink)](targetlink)` combines the two - description is just left empty here)